# php PDO extending

Tags: php, class, pdo, extending

I'm not trying to create my own PDO class, just extend it so I can insert a try catch statement in my own execute function (myexecute) so I do not have to write the code every time.

Firstly, is this a good ideas? or should I just scrap it?

so I want this:

```
$DB = new Database ( HOST, DB, USER, PASS );
$query = $DB->prepare("INSERT * FROM books WHERE title = :title");
$query->bindParam( ':title', $_POST['title'] );
$query->myexecute();
```

if there was a problem my function (myexecute) would sort the error handling
the problem is Im getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::myexecute()
```

Any ideas what Im doing wrong?

```
 class Database extends PDO
    {
    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $total;
    private $p_query;


    public function __construct($hostname,$dbname,$username,$password)
    {
        try  
        { 
            $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$hostname.';dbname='.$dbname;
            parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password);
        } 
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "DataBase Error: Connection error.<br>".$e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    } 

    public function myexecute()
    {
        try 
        {
            return parent::execute();
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
            echo "DataBase Error: The user could not be added.<br>".$e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }   
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            echo "General Error: The user could not be added.<br>".$e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `$query` is an object of `PDOStatement` class.

Comment: `prepare()` returns `PDOStatement` object, not `PDO` object.

Comment: ahh i didnt know that. So how do I go about doing what I want.

Comment: do i simply extend the PODStatement class?

Comment: You are not configuring PDO to throw exceptions.

Comment: You're doing it completely wrong - it won't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You don't have to write try catch statement with raw PDO either.

So, the reason you are trying to extend PDO for is a false one.

Just quit that bad habit of writing try catch on every statement and you'll be fine with raw PDO.

Comment: Right, think i'll just scrap what I'm doing and do it normally. cheers for everyones input

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are trying to do, you'd have to write a wrapper around PDOStatement and override the prepare method in your Database class to return that wrapper of PDOStatement. So that you can have a method myexecute in your subclass of PDOStatement.

Answer (score 0):

Wanting to extend PDOStatement is quite common and is supported by PDO.  You just need to specify which class to use for statements.

```
class DBIStatement extends \PDOStatement
{
    public function fetchrow_hash()
    {
        $rows = $this->fetchAll();
        return (count($rows) == 1) ? new DBIDataRow($rows[0]) : new DBIDataRow(array());
    }
}
class DBI
{
    public $dbh;

    public function __construct($type, $host, $name, $user, $pass)
    {   
        $dsn = sprintf('%s:host=%s;dbname=%s',$type,$host,$name);
        $this->dbh = new \PDO($dsn,$user,$pass,array(
            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,           PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        ));
        // *** This is what tells PDO to use your statement class.
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS,array('DBIStatement'));
    }
```

Don't be alarmed by the back slashes.  This is part of a namespaced application.

The only strange thing is that I could not pass the statement class in the pdp constructor like I could wit the other attributes.  But is does work.

No need to fool with the pdo prepare method at all.

Comment: Nothing common in extending PDO actually.

Comment: At least you explained why you down voted.  You are wrong but that's okay.

Comment: This answer provided exactly what I was looking for, in explaining how to get PDO to return my a custom Statement class. Thank you! :)